# is it possible to get amount of tabs opened in Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, imacros

I want to iterate over opened tabs and do specific tasks.
Is there a way to get the amount of opened tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a js-script, I hope the following code should be helpful:

```
var wM = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var numberOfTabs = wM.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").gBrowser.browsers.length;
```

Comment: This will only get the tabs for one window, but users can have multiple windows opened.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way that Firefox [currently uses](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/92d11a33250a8e368c8ca3e962e15ca67117f765/browser/modules/BrowserUsageTelemetry.jsm#101-111) to count opened windows and tabs, for telemetry:

```
function getOpenTabsAndWinsCounts() {
  let tabCount = 0;
  let winCount = 0;

  for (let win of Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser")) {
    winCount++;
    tabCount += win.gBrowser.tabs.length;
  }

  return { tabCount, winCount };
}
```

Please note how it iterates through the results of `Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser")`, to capture the numbers of all the different opened windows.

Depending on where you want to use the script, you might need to use `var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)` rather than `Services.wm`, as suggested by @Shugar.